# Exclusive use of WebP instead of PNG in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, png, webp

Android Studio 2.3 is released and it now supports WebP format also. My question is, can I completely dump PNG format for images and use WebP format instead? Is it possible to completely use WebP images only instead of PNGs everywhere in the app?

Comment: WebP itself is only supported on Android 4.0+. Lossless WebP (akin to PNG) and transparency support (also akin to PNG) is only available on Android 4.3+. So, at minimum, your use of WebP will depend on your `minSdkVersion` and your image requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per google

> Because support for lossless and transparent WebP images is only
>   available in Android 4.3 and higher, your project must declare a
>   minSdkVersion of 18 or higher to create lossless or transparent WebP
>   images using Android Studio.

You can find more about webp and its usage at [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html)